# How to prevent browsers from remembering checkbox state?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, browser, autocomplete

In a web form, when I programatically uncheck checkboxes which was previously checked, the browsers try to "remember" the previous state and check them again after postback.

Is there anything similar to `autocomplete=off` to accomplish this? Anyway, how can I prevent the browser from checking checkboxes which I want to become unchecked?

Comment: Sounds like ASP.Net, not the browser

Comment: No, I checked the generated HTML, and the checkbox does not have the "checked" attribute.

Comment: what's in your pages ViewState? http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Comment: Have you tried setting the Enabled="False" property... Just to see if that keeps it from being checked.  If it gets checked anyway then it is being checked in the code.

Comment: I am sure that's not being checked using server code (checked the HTML output) and the page does not contain client side scripts.

Answer (score 3):

you can run some javascript code (once DOM is ready and the checkbox exists on page):

```
var allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

// loop on all checkboxes found (trick to iterate on nodeList)
[].forEach.call(allCheckboxes, function (checkbox) {
    checkbox.checked = checkbox.defaultChecked;
});
```