# browser back + viewscope beans

Tags: jsf-2, back-button

**What the problem is** :
What happens when clicking on the browser back button --> opens up a page whose viewscoped-managedbean is already destroyed --> submit a request from a commandButton from that page with grid-record-selections ?

**What i expect** :
The associated viewscope-managebean is re-created, receives the grid-record-selections, and deal with them as if the browser back button is never involved.

**What i experience** :
The associated viewscope-managebean is NOT re-created, doesnt receive the grid-record-selections. Have to reenter the URL, or F5 after clicking on the browser-back button for it to work properly again.

So here's the **success scenario**, all beans are viewscoped beans :

1. GET page1.xhtml --> page1Bean created, querying data, etc in @PostConstruct
2. check/select several records from a datatable, click on process button
3. page1Bean's process method stores the selected records in the flash object, and redirect to the page2.xhtml
4. page1Bean destroyed, page2Bean created, and in preRenderView listener method, fetches the selected records from the flash object, and deal with them
5. click the "go to main page" commandButton to redirect to page1.xhtml, and page2Bean destroyed, page1Bean created again
6. loop from no 2 - 5 is still doable

Now, this is the **errornous scenario** involving the browser back button (different stuffs happening starting from #6) :

1. GET page1.xhtml --> page1Bean created, querying data, etc in @PostConstruct
2. check/select several records from a datatable, click on process button
3. page1Bean's process method stores the selected records in the flash object, and redirect to the page2.xhtml
4. page1Bean destroyed, page2Bean created, and in preRenderView listener method, fetches the selected records from the flash object, and deal with them
5. *click the browser back button page2Bean is not destroyed, page1Bean is not created*
6. check/select several records from a datatable, click on process button
7. the page1Bean method executes (strange, because the page1Bean should've been destroyed), but cannot see the record-selections made, and redirect to page2.xhtml
8. page1Bean is not destroyed (no logging output), page2Bean is not created (since it's not been destroyed), executes the preRenderView listener as usual, but this time, no selected records in the flash object

Is it possible to have the normal experience (as if without the browser back button) with viewscope-beans with the browser back button ?

Here's my dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please share your ideas !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The browser seems to have served the page from its cache instead of sending a fullworthy HTTP GET request to the server, while you have JSF state saving method set to `server` (which is the default).

There are 2 ways to solve this problem:

1. Tell the browser to not cache the dynamic JSF pages. You can do this with help of a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info).

   ```
   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
       HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
       HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

       if (!req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
           res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
           res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
           res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
       }

       chain.doFilter(request, response);
   }
   ```

   Map the filter on the `FacesServlet` or its same URL-pattern.
2. Set the JSF state saving method to client, so that the entire view state is stored in a hidden field of the form instead of in the session in the server side.

   ```xml
   <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
       <param-value>client</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```

The filter way is preferable.

Comment: thanks for source example :) i tried changing the the state saving method to client, i kinda freaked out, i have to change many beans and domain beans into serializable. so, tried the filter and worked great ! although with a lil bit of worry with this article here : http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2006/08/08/disable-browser-caching-in-jsf/ which states it's not guaranteed. But in my experience here, it works very well.

Comment: Doing this in a `PhaseListener` is clumsy. As to the guarantee, well, he has got a point, but all modern browsers (IE, FF, GC, AS, O, etc) respect the HTTP caching rules properly. It will only probably fail when the client uses some dubious browser.

Comment: But there's one thing though, when clicking the browser back button, the checkboxes inside p:datatable which were selected are still checked, but when submitted, they're actually not checked. This happens in google chrome 15, but not firefox 5.0.1. I think it's the same situation as this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100741/how-to-prevent-browsers-from-remembering-checkbox-state .I want to try using randomized form names as stated in the solution, but im not sure how to refresh another form inside a form in a page with multiple forms if i dont know the names of the outer form.

Comment: This is indeed browser specific. You'd need to add `autocomplete="off"` to the `<form>`. This is unfortunately not supported by `<h:form>`, you might want to use a custom `UIForm` renderer or some JS/jQuery for this, or just to add it to the individual input elements. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

Answer (score 0):

The disadvantage of disabling the browser cache of a page is that the user will see an browsers error page if he use browser back to navigate to previous page. 
So another solutions is to identify if the page comes from the server or from the browser cache using javascript:

First create a simple backing bean which serves a unique id (in my case current system time):

```
@Named("browserCacheController")
@RequestScoped
public class BrowserCacheController implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
/**
 * Returns a unique increasing id for each request
 * @return
 */
public long getCacheID() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis();
}   
}
```

So now you can test if a page is served from the server or browser and redirecting the user if the current page comes from browser cache. See the following javascript code placed into a jsf page which should not be cached by browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // check for latestCacheID
    if (!isValidCacheID(#{browserCacheController.cacheID})) {
        //redirect to some page
        document.location="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/index.jsf";
    }

    // test cacheID if it comes from the server....
    function isValidCacheID(currentCacheID) {
        if (!('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null))
            return true; // old browsers not supported
        var latestCacheID=localStorage.getItem("org.imixs.latestCacheID");
        if (latestCacheID!=null && currentCacheID<=latestCacheID) {
            return false; // this was a cached browser page!
        }
        // set new id
        localStorage.setItem("org.imixs.latestCacheID", currentCacheID);
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

The script can also be placed into facelet to make the jsf code more clean.

Comment: You should just not use POST to navigate.